# What properties does a state $|\psi\rangle$ need to fulfill to be a quantum state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-states

So this year I have started studying quantum mechanics and I still have some conceptual difficulties understanding quantum states and how they can be treated in mathematically rigorous ways.

In fact, I am not fully sure of what can be regarded as a proper quantum state. I understand it has to fulfill the following points:

- It has to be normalized (i.e $|\langle \psi|\psi\rangle|^2=1$).
- The function $|\psi(x)|^2$ such that $\int\psi(x)|x\rangle dx=|\psi\rangle$ has to be continuous. As it is its probability density function.
- It needs to live in a Hilbert space $\cal{H}$, which for the continuous case I am studying is $\cal{L}^2$ the space of square-integrable complex functions with Lebesgue measure.

Is this enough? Or are there some additional required properties for $|\psi\rangle$ to be regarded as a quantum state?

Comment: Ok, so now the answer depends entirely on what you think "proper" means. For example, by "proper" do you mean "physically producible"? Do you mean "within the domain of all relevant operators"? Etc.

Comment: Basically, it looks enough. Why would you fuss about exceptions?